# What to do about network failures when loading crossdomain.xml policy file?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, facebook, security, facebook-graph-api

I monitor (and log to server) most user errors in our flash game. Quite frequently I see security errors related to trying to make requests to a cross-domain URL (usually the Facebook Graph API). 99% of our players can make these graph API calls with no issues.

What I think is going on is that the client makes a request, but fails to load the `crossdomain.xml` file. I don't quite know how AS3 handles this in the case of a failure to load the crossdomain policy file...will it retry for every `URLRequest` made until it succeeds in loading it, or does it just give up forever? What's the "best practice" in response to a security error like this?

I am pre-loading the Facebook policy files once, ahead of time, like this:

```
// allow images to be loaded from facebook and facebook's cdn's.
Security.loadPolicyFile( "http://www.facebook.com/crossdomain.xml" );
Security.loadPolicyFile( "https://api.facebook.com/crossdomain.xml" );
Security.loadPolicyFile( "https://graph.facebook.com/crossdomain.xml" );
Security.loadPolicyFile( "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/crossdomain.xml" );
```

then I also have flash check the policy file again when making the `URLRequest`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that appears to work.

Assuming you are using a `URLLoader` to read data from one of the domains that has a crossdomain.xml file and you are calling `loadPolicyFile` to preload crossdomain.xml, there is a chance that the load will fail, either from network connectivity issues or from a server being down, or from solar flares.  When you set up your `URLLoader`, you can add an event listener for `SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR`.  In the even listener, you can try loading the policy file again.  The policy files get cached though, even when they fail to load (thanks adobe), so you'll have to add a cache busting query parameter.

Here is a simple example of how this would work:

```
public function loadMyFriends():void {
  var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
  urlLoader.addEventListener(
    SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, handleSecurityError);
  urlLoader.load(new URLRequest('https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends'));
}

private function handleSecurityError(event:Event):void {
  Security.loadPolicyFile(
    "https://graph.facebook.com/crossdomain.xml?__cb"=Math.random());
  loadMyFriends();
}
```

In practice, you would probably want to limit the number of retries and maybe do an exponential back-off if it really is a network connectivity issue and not just a dead server that isn't being properly handled by a load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

My tests have shown that it retries up to every 10 seconds or so, so I guess it should be possible to show an error message and try again after a few seconds.